# how to use onchoice() in select option?

Tags: javascript, select

I don't know how to use onchoice() in select tag which includes javascript function also.Because in most of the sites they have given javascript+form+submit.But I want javascript+select+onchoice.Can anybody help me
Thank you.

Comment: onChoice does not exist. Use `.change()` or `.on('change')` if you are using `jQuery`, `onchange = myFunc()` if you expcted to use it in your HTML or `element.onchange = myFunc` in Javascript. Remember to set it without `()` or it will exec inmediatly when the element is loaded.

Answer (score 1):

In JavaScript, there in no event `onChoice()` you can use `onchange()` in that you can get the selected value

```
<select id="box1" onChange="call(this.value);">
    <option value="1" >1</option>
    <option value="2" >2</option>
    </select>

  <script>
  function call(value)
  {
  alert(value);
  }
  </script>
```

jQuery code:

```
$('#box1').change(function(){
      alert($(this).val());
  });
```

Comment: Man, just write onchange, onChange doesn't exists

Answer (score 1):

If you are using jQuery, the event you are looking for is called [change()](http://api.jquery.com/change/).